# Calculating Fraction in Power BI Returns Unwanted Values At Empty Intersections

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table with multiple columns which comes from different data sources. in which 2 columns are Actual Number and Expected Number(both measures). I have to create a new column in the table which just shows Actual Number/Expected Number.

Few rows have blanks for both Actual and Expected, for which i have to show "N/A". I was able to achieve the first part where we just show actual/expected, But challenge is when changing the logic to show N/A for blank values of actual and expected columns.

What I tried:

Created a measure, this works perfectly for non-blanks

`IF([Actual] >0,[Actual]&"/"&[Expected])`

I changed the measure to this to show N/A for blanks:

`IF(ISBLANK([Actual]) ||ISBLANK([Expected]),"N/A",IF([Actual] >0,[Actual]&"/"&[Expected]))`

when I try the above, the no of rows in the table drastically increases creating duplicates and I get many records with "N/A", where I only have 1 row which has blank actual/expected. I'm unsure what is causing the issue and want to know what is the best way to approach this. Thanks in advance

Comment: How does it look like when defined as a calculated column instead?

Comment: Can you show your sample data and expected output?

Answer (score 1):

The likely issue is that, depending on your data model structure, there are a large number of unused intersections on whichever dimensions you are evaluating over. This typically happens when there is no defined relationship between fact tables (your visual is essentially performing an open `CROSSJOIN()`). Without seeing your table structure, I would assume this is the issue. To fix:

1. Create one or more shared dimension tables as applicable
2. Create relationships between each fact table (Actual/Expected) and the shared dimension(s) as applicable.
3. Change your table visual to use the new shared dimensions instead of the  fact table columns.

What may help is to only return `NA` when one expression is blank, but not both.

```
VAR actual = [Actual]
VAR expected = [Expected]
RETURN
    IF (
        ISBLANK ( actual ) || ISBLANK ( expected ) ,
        "NA",
        IF ( actual > 0, actual & "/" & expected )
    )
```

Additionally, I added variables for `[Actual]` & `[Expected]` so that they are each only evaluated once.

---

[image]

Comment: should i do this in a calculated column or a measure?

Comment: This should work with either. I typically prefer measures for aggregations, but you should be fine either way.

Comment: thanks, i tried both the above dax in a measure and looks like it doesn't print the NA, the results look unchanged, but NA doesn't work.

Comment: What is your table/relationship structure, and what are your two existing measure definitions?

Comment: Typically this behavior is from an ambiguous relationship issue, not a measure issue. Are there common dimensions tables between each fact table, and are you using the fact table columns in the visual?

Comment: @jahan, did the updated measure work, and were you able to check which table columns are being used in the visual?

Answer (score 0):

Possible that the divide function might help (at least with the denominator).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/best-practices/dax-divide-function-operator

Answer (score 0):

Merge the two columns `[Actual]` and `[Expected]` into `OneColumn`

From `OneColumn` create a new column `CheckBlankString` to check for blank Strings:

```
CheckBlankString = SWITCH(TRUE(),Table[OneColumn] = BLANK(), "N/A",
Table[Column] <> BLANK(), Table[OneColumn])
```

This will give you `N/A` for all your empty rows or blanks.